# How Do I build A PDF Find and Replace Text App and Automate PDF Processing?

Tags: pdf, ocr, file-conversion

I need help creating a solution that would help me resolve PDF text replacement. We hired a programmer that tried to achieve our objective with a python-coded app but failed.

Our project hopes to automate these steps:

1. Get a folder with pdf documents
2. In Each document, we need to find particular text (usually in the upper third of the page). The information can be on multiple pages.
3. Hide/erase/ and replace the text with different information that we would pull from excel or SQL database. Make sure that the text is replaced on all occasions.
4. Next, rename the document based on the assigned doc name (pulled from excel or SQL).
5. Have a report of all documents that were processed and when the new version was and was not created.
6. Keep the original document saved for review and comparison.

I am happy to provide the original code from the developers if necessary, but it did not work...

Thank you for your help, community!

Comment: Replacing text in a random PDF is a non-trivial exercise. Were you in control of how the documents were created in the first place? Is it OK if the new words overlap the text near the words it replaced?

Comment: Indeed, the question here is whether any simplifying assumptions can be made for the input pdfs in respect to how the text to replace is drawn. Is it drawn using text showing instructions? If yes, does the font in question contain the information required for mapping to Unicode? Alternatively, is the text drawn using vector graphics? Or part of a bitmap? In either case, is it drawn as a whole in one piece or is its drawing spread in pieces over the whole content stream (or even over multiple ones)? And is the text drawn the same way in the different documents? Etc. Etc. Etc.

Comment: @joelgeraci No, we get several different reports from several different sites. However, they all have one thing in common. Data we want to find and replaced.

-KJ hired. We used Upwork to find a developer that could help us. He decided to use python in combination with machine learning but he could never automate the process of finding and replacing data in pdfs that were in a folder. Hence no automation was really possible. 
-mkl The pdfs were all readable, the font was always the same and the data was almost always in the upper 3rd of the doc. so if you ctrl+f you could find the data...

Comment: I'm not going to suggest that this is ***impossible*** but it will be extremely difficult and likely error-prone until you have gathered enough PDF files from various PDF creation tools to develop the heuristics to detect words no matter how they are painted on the page. A better approach than search/replace would be to find the word to be replaced, put a white box over it, then put the replacement in the same exact space adjusting the font spacing and/or size so that it fits without overlapping anything around it.

Comment: @joelgeraci that's kinda the approach the developer used. Found it placed the white box over it to hide the original, and then tried to put the new text over it. However, he could not make it work and automate the process by using a bulk upload and creating a report that would help us understand if the given pdf report was successfully edited or not.

Comment: The reporting and verification is a separate issue and totally solvable. You may have just needed a different developer.